# Only one credential of a type seems allowed?

Tags: azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

In Microsoft Azure AD Verifiable Credentials if you try to issue a credential of the same contract URI a second time to the the MS Authenticator wallet it prompts that you already have such a credential.

1. Is there a flag to allow multiple credentials of a type?
2. Is it the contract URI that must be unique to not receive the duplicate message?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is a self imposed limitation in Authenticator to only allow one verifiable credential of a 'credentialType'.

We have a backlog item to remove this limitation. Additionally once we remove the limitation we will also need to give the user the ability to select which VC they want to present when a request would satisfy more than one VC in Wallet. This is the main reason for the current limitation.

Comment: Michael, you can have multiple of the same VC schema/credentialType on Android. Feature coming soon to iOS